# How to launch dotnet core mvc app on a different port?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-code, .net-core-2.2

My `dotnetcoreapp2.2` application runs fine under `port 5001` (after configuring the [dev cert](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx)) but I cannot get it to launch under any other port. Here are the components I've attempted configuring...

Program.cs:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseUrls("http://localhost:5000")  
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights();
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsEnvironment("Developer"))
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

launch.json:

```
        "args": [
            "--urls", "http://localhost:5000"
        ],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "launchBrowser": {
            "enabled": true,
            "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
            "windows": {
                "command": "cmd.exe",
                "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
            }
        },
        "env": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Developer",
            "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "http://localhost:5000"
        },
```

Am I missing something or have something configured incorrectly?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This issue generally occurs when using IIS / IIS Express, so rid of the IIS.

Run web server as .net core console application, instead of using IIS Express(it has own port configuration file for each project, and it is annoying).

**To do that:** Change Debug Profile in `Project's Properties > Debug >`

1. change the value of `Profile` from IIS Express to "`select-your-project-name`"
2. change the value of `Launch` from IIS or IIS Express to `Project`
3. Then, you will see `Web Server Settings` on bottom of the same window, you can use it to change port(IIS configs are not using anymore).
4. Also you should change default debugger from `IIS Express` to "`select-your-project-name`" (you will see where you clicked to debug your project)